# Icons in desktop appearance!

Tags: icons

I need a little help on desktop icons which drives me really mad.

First of all, i should say i'm very very happy with ubuntu (i'm new on Linux) except this problem.

To be more specific, i have 2 main problems:

1) When icon names are long enough to spread to the second line of "icon name box", its being splitted into two parts.As an example:

Let's imagine a file name is: "This is my veryveryverylong filename".
In Windows:

" This is my
  veryveryverylong
  filename"

But in Ubuntu it splits words of filenames:
" This is m/y veryver/yverylon/gfilenam/e"

or another example: instead of "Mathematics", "Mathe/matics"

So you get the point. (Backslash means the writing of filename spreads to a second line.)

2) In windows we can lock icons when we drag and drop them.It's like there are specific locked (x,y) position spots that whenever we drag and drop an icon, it locks itself into the closest spot which i think very very useful for desktop appearance.

However, on Ubuntu, when i drag and drop an icon, it just sticks to the exact point i dropped.

So do we have any solutions for these 2 appearance problems.

Thanks from now for any help guys!
Long live free OS's and the idea of helping each other! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The answer for both your questions is MATE DE:

[image: solution]

You can install it with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^`.

Comment: I think i have solved the problem with upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04, but thanks for the tip anyway ;)